# 2to3 bug: tuple index out of range, fix_raise

Tags: python-2to3

I have found what looks like a not tested case to me. When trying to convert following code with 2to3:

```
def test(arg): 
    raise()
```

The execution stops ungracefully with no indication why, nor what file caused the problem, this is very annoying if you are trying to convert a whole folder of python 2  scripts. The following is thrown:

```
...
exc= exc.children[1].children[0].clone()
IndexError: tuple out of range
```

I am expecting to obtain a *BadInput* exception. Clearly, given the source code just above, it is expecting `raise("something")` and since there is no check that "children" inside the tuple of `raise ()` is even present, this causes error.

Please correct me if I  am wrong, of course `raise()` is incorrect, but this should not crash the execution, likewise the following:

```
def test(arg): 
    print 1.method()
```

Throws *BadInput* exception with a clear indication what happened.